# how to add HREF link on each row using Vuetables VUE.JS

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-tables-2

I've been working VUEJS Vuetables, despite I read about components and slots I cannot figure how to add a link with the following structure on each row:

```
<td class="text-center">
<a href="{{ url('/order/'.$order->id) }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i>
</a>
</td>
```

1- I created a the column

```
        data: {
            columns: [
                {
                    name: '__component:gcp-actions',
                    title: 'Actions',
                    titleClass: 'text-center',
                    dataClass: 'text-center'
                }
```

2- I created gcpaction component:

```
<template>
    <div class="custom-actions">
        <a v-bind:href="rowData.view" v-if="show" class="btn btn-flat bg-green btn-sm"><i
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i></a>
        <button class="btn btn-flat bg-red btn-sm" @click="itemAction('delete-item', rowData, rowIndex)"><i
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
    </div>
</template>
```

I tried with `<a>` and with `<button>`

3- I registered the component in my table:

```
import GcpActions from './GcpActions'
Vue.component('gcp-actions', GcpActions)
```

4- When I render I can see the whole table but I cannot see the component in my table:

```
<vtable url="orders/filter" :columns="columns" :filters="filters"></vtable>
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [scoped slots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#scoped-slots)?

```
<span slot="columnName" slot-scope="props">
    <a href="/profiles/{{columnName.if}}"></a>
</span>
```